# Is it possible to build a huge spaceship like the one of of Star Trek or Prometheus?

Tags: rocket-science, space-travel

Ok, so theoretically, is it possible to build a spaceship like the ones we see off of Star Trek or Prometheus or will physics not allow it? What are some challenge faces such an task. Also, is there other ways we can use to launch heavier payload from earth or are we just stuck with using tons of fuel to launch small object?

Comment: Even in Star Trek, they build Starships in space. Just take components or 3D printers from Earth to Space and start building..

Comment: One could build ships the size of small asteroids, if one wanted to. What these ships couldn't do, is to accelerate fast without being crushed by their own engines. Your aversion against rockets is simply based on your beliefs, that they aren't efficient. In reality, though, rockets are actually fairly efficient, far more so than one would assume naively. In any case, one could do slightly better than that with electromagnetic mass drivers and space elevators, but neither concept scales well for planets much larger than Mars. On Earth rockets are pretty much as good as it gets.